# Pandas dataframe: how to group by values in a column and create new columns out of grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
x y
0 1
1 1
2 2
0 5
1 6
2 8
0 1
1 8
2 4
0 1
1 7
2 3
```

What I want is:

```
x val1 val2 val3 val4
0 1 5 1 1
1 1 6 8 7
2 2 8 4 3
```

I know that the values in column x are repeated all N times.

Comment: I think that a column header is missing in your expected output, since you have five num columns and four headers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `groupby/cumcount` to assign column numbers and then call `pivot`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
                   'y': [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 1, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3]})

df['columns'] = df.groupby('x')['y'].cumcount()
#     x  y  columns
# 0   0  1        0
# 1   1  1        0
# 2   2  2        0
# 3   0  5        1
# 4   1  6        1
# 5   2  8        1
# 6   0  1        2
# 7   1  8        2
# 8   2  4        2
# 9   0  1        3
# 10  1  7        3
# 11  2  3        3

result = df.pivot(index='x', columns='columns')
print(result)
```

yields

```
         y         
columns  0  1  2  3
x                  
0        1  5  1  1
1        1  6  8  7
2        2  8  4  3
```

---

Or, if you can really rely on the values in `x` being repeated *in order* N times,

```
N = 3
result = pd.DataFrame(df['y'].values.reshape(-1, N).T)
```

yields

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  5  1  1
1  1  6  8  7
2  2  8  4  3
```

Using `reshape` is quicker than calling `groupby/cumcount` and `pivot`, but it
is less robust since it relies on the values in `y` appearing in the right order.